# reload page fail after success in jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui

after success my page wont reload but it just close the window

this is my **jQuery script**

```
jQuery("#edit").dialog({
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    draggable: false,
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 400,
    buttons: [
        {
            text: "Ok",
            click: function() {
                var message = "";

                var id = jQuery.trim(jQuery("#id").val());
                var fname = jQuery.trim(jQuery("#firstname").val());
                var lname = jQuery.trim(jQuery("#lastname").val());
                var email = jQuery.trim(jQuery("#email").val());
                var telephone = jQuery.trim(jQuery("#telephone").val());
                var mobile = jQuery.trim(jQuery("#mobile").val());
                var address = jQuery.trim(jQuery("#address").val());
                var bdate = jQuery.trim(jQuery("#bdate").val());

                if (fname == "") {message += "Please enter firstname\n"};
                if (lname == "") {message += "Please enter lastname\n"};
                if (email == "") {
                    message += "Please enter email\n"
                }
                else{
                    if(!ValidateEmail(email)){
                        message += "Please enter valid email address.\n"
                    }
                }

                if (telephone == "") {message += "Please enter telephone\n"};
                if (mobile == "") {message += "Please enter mobile\n"};
                if (address == "") {message += "Please enter address\n"};
                if (bdate == "") {message += "Please enter birthdate"};

                if (message != "")
                {
                    alert(message);
                    return false;
                }
                else    
                {
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "json",
                        url: "update.php",
                        async:true,
                        data: {                         
                            "id": id,
                            "firstname": fname,
                            "lastname": lname,
                            "email": email,
                            "telephone": telephone,
                            "mobile": mobile,
                            "address": address,
                            "bdate": bdate                          
                        },
                        sucess: function(){
                            window.location.reload(true);
                            }
                    });
                }
            }
        },
        {
            text: "Cancel",
            click: function() {
                jQuery(this).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

and here is my **PHP**

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
$mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$bdate = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($_POST['bdate']));

$sql = "UPDATE user SET
        firstname='$firstname', lastname='$lastname', email='$email', telephone='$telephone', mobile='$mobile', address='$address', bdate='$bdate' WHERE id=$id";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        if($result){
            echo json_encode(array(
            "success" => true,
            ));
        }
```

i tried also this but doesnt reload the page

```
sucess: function(data){
        if(data.success == true){
        window.location.reload(true);
        }
        }
```

also i changed the **window.location.reload** into **location.reload** and i tried also removing the **true** in it

Comment: What about `document.location.reload(true);`

Comment: `sucess: function(){` and `success: function(){` see the difference? You spelled success incorrectly

Comment: @Desperado thank you sir thats the only wrong.